# python2.7: Could not import get_url from bottle

Tags: python, import, importerror, bottle, geturl

I can't import the `get_url` from bottle:

```
from bottle import get_url
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./py_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bottle import get_url
ImportError: cannot import name get_url
```

There is no error when I load any other one like: `run`, `post`, `get`, `route`, `view`, `static_file`, `template`, ...

Comment: When you go@ `import bottle; bottle.get_url` can you actually call this function?

Comment: I can't: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_url'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bottle doesn't seem to expose a `get_url` function. It does have a [`url` function](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L2564), which wraps the `Bottle.get_url` method for the default application.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, i've changed all `get_url` in every file to `url` and it works fine!